# Web View is not displaying after hiding title bar

Tags: android

I've a android application in which i want to hide the `TitleBar` i used the following code in `onCreate` method of `activity.java`   `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`hiding the Title bar is Solved But the `webview` is blank, if i refresh the page den the content of `webView` will be displayed is there any solution for this?.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: did'nt get you.Please explain yourself more clearly if you want to save yourself from -1

Comment: Is your problem with title bar of webview not loading?

Comment: @NeZam I used requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); to hide title bar. My title bar is hide now but webview is not loading.

Comment: First of all, Your question isn't clear. Second, I don't know why you got alternatives of hiding titlebar answers rather than the answers that solve your content loading problem .

Comment: Then why is the title "Hiding Title bar in Android"?. You just confused the hell out of everyone. Is the webpage also blank if you remove requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);?

Comment: @EdwardvanRaak No if i remove requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); webview contents is displaying

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

in `manifest` file activity tag instead of `onCreate()` method.

That is working properly in my apps.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

You should call this before your setContentView() method.

Edit:

Without knowing *how* and *when* you create the webview it's hard to guess what's going on but you could always do a `WebView.reload()` after you create the webview because that apparently fixes the problem.

Comment: I'm creating webview in public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) method webview.reload() is not working.

Comment: Try to create the webview inside the onCreate() of the Activty before the setContentView() method?

Answer (score 0):

```
setTitle("");
```

On your oncreate method..